# Matlab matrix-multiplication and transpose precision

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, transpose

The next script should print out a 7x7 all-ones matrix, because the equation is satisfied.

```
A = rand(5,7);
B = rand(5,7);

C = (A' * B)';
D =  B' * A;

C == D
```

Instead of this kind of answer:

```
ans =

 1     1     1     1     0     1     1
 1     1     1     1     0     1     0
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     0     0     0
 1     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     1     1     0     1     1     1
```

I think this is a floating-point precision problem, because with `format long` the numbers differ in C and D.

- What do I do wrong?
- Where does it go wrong?
- How can I avoid it?

Comment: *I think this is a floating-point precision problem [...]*. Yes. Because `rand` returns floating-point numbers, you shouldn't expect matrices `C` and `D` to be exactly equal. Prefer something like `norm(C - D) <= epsilon`, where `epsilon` is a small positive number.

Answer (score 4):

You don't do anything wrong - the computer has finite precision, and your calculation reveals it - just like `1e6 + 0.1 - 1e6` (try it in Matlab). One way to avoid it is to use some library for arbitrary precision - but it won't 'solve' it, just push the problem towards smaller and smaller numbers.

See these links for some more info:

http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

By the way, `format long` has nothing to do with the actual precision, it just sets the way the numbers are formatted for **displaying**.